# railsで保存した直後にデータを加工したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsで保存した直後に保存したデータをupdateしたいのですが、どうしたらよいのでしょうか。

```
def after_save
  self.update(:name => self.name + 'ほげほげ')
end
```

このような感じでカラムのデータを書き換えるような事を想定しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

保存するデータを書き換えたいということであれば、`before_save` を使うと良いです。

```
class Hogege < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :fix_name

  private

  def fix_name
    self.name += "ほげほげ"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

モデルを保存した直後に、属性を更新するには`after_save`コールバックで`update_column`メソッドを実行します。具体的なコードは次のとおりです。

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save do
    update_column(:name, "#{@name}ほげほげ")
  end
end
```

ポイントは、[update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column)です。update_columnは、バリデーションとコールバックを実行しません。